# is it a good way to use 1-1 relationship in this case?

Tags: database, database-design, relationship

I have a database with a table Ticket containing:

```
[id, user_id, project_id, title, steps_to_reproduce_issue, expected_result, actual_result, additional_comments, ticket_attachment_id, status, priority, categories, date_created, date_modified]
```

is it a good way to put the following attributes `[title, steps_to_reproduce_the_issue, expected result, actual_result, additional_comments]` into separate table TicketDescription, and then to use 1-1 relationship for Ticket-TicketDescription tables, and then just add ticket_description_id into Ticket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I understood your case.

Consider that you have 3 occasions of the same show. (i.e. diffrent hours) - You would be better to reuse the TicketDescription for the 3 occasions, Right?

So in my point of view it's better to use `1 to many` relation instead of declaring every time the description.

Think well about the distribution of the fields.

Comment: The OP is looking to create a 1-1 relationship.  Your example (while correct) is a 1-many relationship.